# tweets are not storing in csv file.i tried so many methods .Actually i getting tweets but they are not storing in my workbook

Tags: python, csv, twitter, tweepy

My code is:

```
import tweepy
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys
#input your credentials here
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('amaravathi.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#amaravathi",count=10,
                       lang="en").items():`
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
    print(tweet.created_at,tweet.text)
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: What isn't working, what is your question?

Comment: Try displaying your current folder, e.g. `print(os.getcwd())` to see where it would be saved to.

Comment: @MartinEvans thank u so much .

Comment: @dspencer   actually it works ...but i don't know where the file stores....thanks to Martin Evans he saved me